# Commonly used url parameters

Tags: web-application, attack-prevention, attack-vector, path-injection

I'm working on a project that requires me to tamper with/rewrite url parameters. I'd also like to add in something that finds request parameters such as

?admin=false

?debugging=false

?page=example

?url=example.php

or anything else along those lines. I was wondering, is there a list I could find of commonly used parameters?

EDIT:
I actually found the answer here, at the owasp dir buster lists download:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dirbuster/files/DirBuster%20Lists/Current/DirBuster-Lists.tar.bz2/download?use_mirror=softlayer-dal&use_mirror=osdn

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question body itself. Post it as a new answer instead. Thanks!

Comment: Plazmaz - one of the best things to do before asking a question is to search to see if it is already here and has an answer. Have a read of [ask] for useful guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's Right !
Just be careful when showing some ID on the URL that can give exceed information to a hacker ... and make parameters for that ID's and information. [SQL Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/sql-injection-but-why-isnt-escape-quotes-safe-anymore)