# SQL Injection through addslashes

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I'm trying to understand how a website can be hacked through using `addslashes` in PHP and MySQL for educational purpose.

After reading [this topic](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) and [this topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/sql-injection-why-isnt-escape-quotes-safe-anymore), I try to understand how it can bypass with something like `0xbf27` that can be converted to `0xbf5c27` through using `addslashes`.

So I manually execute a query for setting Character Set.

```
set character set 'gbk';
```

The character for this purpose must be `뼧` that is `bf27`.According what they say in the above topics it must be convert to something like `bf5c27` but when I test it in my lab with a PHP code like this :

```
$query  = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '".addslashes($id)."';";
echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( '<pre>' . mysql_error() . '</pre>' );
```

And when I insert `뼧` in my text field the exact query that executes is :

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '뼧';
```

So it seems that nothing specially happened !

After this I try to build another PHP script to understand what is going on so I build a simple script without any MySQL execution (test.php) like :

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 
$command = $_REQUEST[ 'id' ];;
$output = addslashes($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Then I execute the file with URL like :

```
http://127.0.0.1/test.php?id=뼧
```

And if you see the above PHP code it echos:

```
ë¼§
```

The hex code of above 3 character is:

```
eb bc a7
```

Well I just think about what happened,

My questions are :

1. What are `ë¼§` that it showed me ?(It seemed something unusual because it doesn't contain anything like `5c` or `27` ?
2. Why the first script doesn't show something like above three character in `echo $query;` ?
3. How can I perform it truly like they describe(In above 2 topics) ?

**Update 1 :**
Thanks to what [Goktay Kaykusuz](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/98310/goktay-kaykusuz) says I understand that I have problem in my encoding. the POC for it is I test it on Terminal and it resaluts :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <pre>뼧</pre> </body>
</html>
```

so I understand that it converts the result to UTF8 (in Chrome) but in Terminal works normally.

But the problem is still alive because it works without any wonderful bypassing (It is just what a simple string should be.)

Answer (score 2):

Funny thing, I've experimented with an online encoding converter. I think you have an encoding problem on the client side.

When I embedded the string inside the PHP code, it worked.

```
$test_var = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27);
echo(bin2dex(addslashes($test_var)));
```

Resulted in: `bf5c27`

The problem is when you get the variable from the URL:

`뼧` after addslashes() results in `ebbca7`

`¿'` after addslashes() result in `bf5c27`

but the [online encoding converter](https://r12a.github.io/apps/encodings/) shows `bf27` for `뼧` and `bf 27` for `¿'`.

Can you set the encoding of your PHP configuration to GBK and UTF-8 in php.ini, then try with the `¿'` characters again? The examples in the links that you've given does not echo the output directly so you might have got scrambled on the client side as I've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. It helps a lot. The encoding in php.ini didn't work like what I expected. I add some more information pls see the update .

Answer (score -1):

```
$query  = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = \"".addslashes($id)."\";";
```

Comment: Can you describe *why* this works?